# How to mock a static variable, which is initialized with a static method call on that static variable

Tags: java, mocking, junit4, jmockit

The following simplified Client wrapper class with a singleton `Client` needs a *unit test* with *JMockit*

```
public class ClientWrapper {
    private static Client client = ClientBuilder
        .build()
        .setProperty("prop1", value);

    public void request(String val) {
        client.target(getfullURL(val)).invoke();
    }
    public String getFullURL(String requestMappingValue) {
        return "http://xxxxx" + requestMappingValue;
    }
}
```

I tried to write unit test with *jmockit 1.18*

```
public class ClientWrapperTest {
    @Tested private ClientWrapper tested;
    @Mocked private Client clientMock;
    @Mocked private Target targetMock;
    @Test
    public void testRequest() {
        //Partial mock on Client class
        new Expectations(Client.class) {{
            ClientBuilder.build();
            result = clientMock;

        }};
        //Partial mock on tested ClientWrapper
        new Expectations(tested) {{
            tested.getFullRUL(anyString);
            result = anyString;
        }};
        //Last mock
        new Expectations() {{
            clientMock.target(anyString);
            result = targetMock;
            targetMock.invoke();
            times = 1;
        }};
        tested.request("/test");
    }
}
```

**Problem**: the `clientMock` is not returned successfully and thus caused the failure of this test

**Question:** How to mock the static method call - `ClientBuilder.build()`, and then continue to make use of the mocked result Client instance to mock `client.invoke()`?

Comment: `Client` should be injected via setter or constructor into `ClientWrapper` for testability. This is really strange that class that should wrap something does not take this object as  dependency somehow.

Comment: @michalk Thanks a lot for your comment :) Seems that my code is a typical anti-pattern. *dependency injection* makes sense here. But I still need to get the *singleton* Client, for instance from a public static method call in a *utility class*, e.g. `public static getClientInstance() { return singletonClient;}` and the `singleCilent` is a static variable retrieved by `ClientBuilder.newClient().setProperty(name, value);`. In this case how to test this static method in the *utility class*?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using a "builder" API like `ClientBuilder.build()` instead of dependency injection. In fact, DI only makes sense for objects that require external configuration (see the [original article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) by Martin Fowler). Even then, using a "Service Locator" might be a better choice (again, see the article, and don't believe people saying that DI is the one and only way - that's cargo cult).

Answer (score 0):

The test shown in the question is over-complicating things, and misusing the mocking API. A correct version of the test would look like the following:

```
public final class ClientWrapperTest {
    @Tested ClientWrapper tested;

    @Test
    public void onRequestCreateAndInvokeTargetURL(@Mocked Client clientMock) {
        tested.request("/test");

        new Verifications() {{
            clientMock.target("http://xxxxx/test").invoke(); times = 1;
        }};
    }

    @Test // assuming "Client" doesn't need to be mocked
    public void onRequestInvokeTargetURL(@Mocked Target targetMock) {
        tested.request("/test");

        new Verifications() {{ targetMock.invoke(); times = 1; }};
    }
}
```

Both tests above should pass, unless `ClientBuilder` does something unexpected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling the problem. But could you tell the detials of the misuse of mocking API in the code? In your code, the `ClientBuilder.build().setProperty("prop1", value)` is not mocked, either

Comment: I honestly tried with your code just now. It can not work with `jmockit` 1.18. What is your version of `jmockit`?

Comment: I used the latest at this time, 1.48.

Comment: About the misuses: 1) `anyString` is an argument matcher, so it has no effect if assigned to the `result` field; 2) unnecessary use of partial mocking; 3) trying to record an expectation on an *unmocked* type (`ClientBuilder`).

Comment: @Rui BTW, I imagine it wasn't you who downvoted my answer. I have actually executed the test class using the code from the question (with the "blanks" filled in from reasonable assumptions) and it works fine (at least with recent versions of JMockit, didn't try with older ones).

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the problem, I really appreciate it. It was actually me who downvoted it, just now I tried to upvote it back and it didn't work anymore. Sorry for this. With version 1.18 I really cannot make the test pass